# Using SUMIF to compare two cells for equality and then sum if there is a match

Tags: excel, formula

I want to to do the following:

- Create SUMIF formula in `Plot` column F, that checks to see if the plotId matches plotId in `Booking`, if there is a match then add the mileage to the total
- For example the `jobMileage` for `plotId` 1 in the `Plot` table should be 17 (3.6 + 13.4). At the moment, I keep getting 0
- This is the formula I'm using on the `Plot` table:

  `=SUMIF(Booking!E:E,A:A=Booking!D:D)`

  but it doesn't seem to be working and only returns 0

A mockup of the tables have been included below:

**Plot**

[image]

**Booking**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SUMIF` formula requires the following format `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`. In your scenario this would be:

`=SUMIF(Booking!D:D,A:A,Booking!F:F)`

Link to tutorial: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx